how to Implement of Grouped mapped pandas UDF in snowflake?
I'm a newcomer to Snowflake. I'm migrating databricks pyspark code in snowflake. In Databricks, I have successfully implemented a grouped mapped Pandas UDF where I pass a Spark DataFrame. However, I'm encountering difficulties replicating the same functionality in Snowflake. While I've managed to implement series UDFs in Snowflake, where both input and output are series, my requirement is to implement a grouped mapped UDF similar to Spark's. This is the example udf i'm trying. I have complex udf to run in snowflake.
Data brick's spark code
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pandas as pd

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["key", "value_1","value_2"])

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("key", StringType(), True),  
    StructField("result", IntegerType(), True) 
])
def sum_values(pdf):
    output_df = pd.DataFrame()
    output_df['key'] = [pdf["key"].iloc[0]]
    output_df['result'] = [pdf["value_1"].iloc[0] + pdf["value_2"].iloc[0]] 
    return output_df
# Apply the Pandas UDF to each group
result_df = df.groupBy("key").applyInPandas(sum_values,schema)
result_df.display()

enter image description here
snowflake code
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.types import *
from snowflake.snowpark.window import *
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import *
import pandas as pd
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    
    # Create a sample Spark DataFrame
    data = [("A", 1,7), ("B", 2,8), ("C", 3,9), ("D", 4,10), ("E", 5,6)]
    df = session.createDataFrame(data, ["key", "value_1","value_2"])
    
    # Define the schema
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("key", StringType(), True),  
        StructField("result", IntegerType(), True)])
    def sum_values(pdf):
        output_df = pd.DataFrame()
        output_df['key'] = [pdf["key"].iloc[0]]
        output_df['result'] = [pdf["value_1"].iloc[0] + pdf["value_2"].iloc[0]] 
        return output_df

    # Apply the Pandas UDF to each group
    #sum_values_udf = session.udf.register(sum_values,return_type=[StringType(),IntegerType()])
    #result_df = df.groupBy("key").applyInPandas(sum_values_udf,schema)

    result_df = df.groupBy("key").applyInPandas(sum_values,schema)
    # Print a sample of the dataframe to standard output.
    result_df.show()

    # Return value will appear in the Results tab.
    return result_df

enter image description here
enter image description here
